# Generic list and value reference

Tags: c#

I have 2 object's let's call them `A`, `B` and method

```
List<B> DoSomething(ref A a, List<B> b)
{
     List<B> newList = new List<B>();

     //
     //Doing something to ref A
     //

     foreach(var elementOfB in b.where(...))
     {
        //
        elementOfB.Name = "...";
        //
        newList.Add(elementOfB);
     }
     return newList;
}
```

So, after that method is done my original list `b` have changed value `Name` field (`string`) but I did not pass it as `ref` and I'm using `where` that should return copy of elemens right? So my question is why my list `b` changed it's values?

```
List<B> originalList = ...;
List<B> newList = DoSomething(ref a, originalList);
//now originalList have changed Name field values
```

Comment: no, where iterates over the elements in the list and does not create a copy. You need to create a copy of the elements manually

Comment: Why are you making such an assumption?

Answer (score 4):

Actually `List<B>` is a list of reference to B elements. The List of reference changed, but the references still point to the same objects.

If a clone object is what you need, take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359318/how-to-clone-objects).

Answer (score 2):

You;re actually doing *shallow coping*: you copy *references to objects*, without *creating clones* of objects:

```
  // Shallow copy (your actual implementation):
  // NewList is not b, but it contains references to objects in b
  var NewList = b
    .Where(item => ...)
    .ToList(); 

  // Deep copy (which probably you're looking for)
  // NewList doesn't contain any reference to any objects in b 
  var NewList = b
    .Where(item => ...)
    .Select(item => item.Clone()) // You need this, proving that Clone() makes a deep copy
    .ToList();
```

If you want to clone the items, you have to implement properly `ICloneable` interface for `B` class (to ensure the *deep coping*)

Comment: `ICloneable` does not guarantee anything. You should probably clarify to the OP that he will still need to implement *deep copying* of his object. Problem with `ICloneable` is that the caller doesn't know what type of clone you're doing.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: thank you, the clarification is really wanted. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> why my list b changed it's values?

Because although you allocated a *new list*, both of them now still point **to the same `B` instance**. You haven't created a new instance prior to adding them to the new list.

An example of how you could clone an existing object, is via a *copy constructor*:

```
public class B
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public B(B other)
    {
        Name = other.name;
    }
}
```

Now when you want to create the list, you do:

```
foreach(var elementOfB in b.Where(SomePredicate))
{
    elementOfB.Name = "...";
    newList.Add(new B(elementOfB));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All types in C# are passed as reference except simple types (int, double etc.). If you want to create a copy you need to do this manually

Answer (score 0):

When b.Where(..).ToList then only copy is created.Where returns IEnumerable which allows you to iterate using foreach loop.

Comment: OP means a copy  of the elements not the list

Answer (score 0):

```
Where(t => IsOk(t));
```

doesn't create a deep copy of the `IEnumerable` on which it's called. It iterates over the collection and returns the items matching the isOk() criteria. Meaning it creates a new list but the items are the same.

If you would like to create a copy of the each of the items you should implement `ICloneable` on the items and Clone them in a new list.