# C# Copy the Class List

Tags: c#, copy

Here is my Class:

```
public class Information
 {
     public Tuple<string, string> pair { get; set; }
     public double Signal { get; set; }
     public double SigmaMove { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
 }

 Inforamtion A = new Information() {};
```

1. I want to use `A.Clone()` but there is no such method?
2. How to Copy a `List<Information> A = B` by value not by reference(Change of A did not influent B, previous solutions in the website do not work .... I tried)?

   ```
   var TodayInformation = YesterdayInformation.Select(o => new Information
           {
               pair = o.pair,
               Signal = o.Signal,
               SigmaMove = o.SigmaMove,
               Date = o.Date,

           }).ToList();
   ```

   If I copy this way, and suppose pair is also a complicate new `Class`(e.g `List<NewClass>`), so  does `pair = o.pair,` need be modified to  guarantee `TodayInformation` is passed by value?
3. When I add a Initializing Constructor in the Class `Information`

   ```
    public class Information
    {
      public Tuple<string, string> pair { get; set; }
      public double Signal { get; set; }
      public double SigmaMove { get; set; }
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }

      public Information(Information Tem)
      {
       pair = Tem.pair;
       Signal  = Tem.Signal ;
       SigmaMove = Tem.SigmaMove;
       Date = Tem.Date;
      }
   }
   ```

Then `Inforamtion A = new Information(){};` this constructor no longer work, is it becasue of covered by the new Constructor? Then how to remain this constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. An object can be cloned implementing `IClonable` interface

   ```
   public class Information : ICloneable
   {
      public Tuple<string, string> pair { get; set; }
      public double Signal { get; set; }
      public double SigmaMove { get; set; }
      public DateTime Date { get; set; }

      public Information(Information Tem)
      {
         pair = Tem.pair;
         Signal  = Tem.Signal ;
         SigmaMove = Tem.SigmaMove;
         Date = Tem.Date;
      }           

      #region ICloneable Members
      public Information Clone() { return new Information(this); }
      object ICloneable.Clone()
      {
         return Clone();
      }
      #endregion
   }
   ```
2. You can copy a list by value. Follow any of the steps below
   If you want to know more about extension method follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx)

**You can use extension method as following**

```
    static class Extensions
    {
      public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> listToClone) where T: ICloneable
      {
         return listToClone.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
      }
    }
```

**OR If you do not want to use IClonable interface**

```
    var InformationList = new List<Information>(infoList);
```

**EDIT**

If there is a nested complex class, make sure you have also implemented `IClonable` interface for that class too and clone it.

3. You can overload a constructor (as Kirlac mentioned)

   ```
   public class Information
   {
     public Tuple<string, string> pair { get; set; }
     public double Signal { get; set; }
     public double SigmaMove { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }

     public Information()
     {}

     public Information(Information Tem)
     {
       pair = Tem.pair;
       Signal  = Tem.Signal ;
       SigmaMove = Tem.SigmaMove;
       Date = Tem.Date;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: 1.`public Information Clone() { return new Information(this); } ` Class `Information` has no constructor `Information()`  2. `var InformationList = new List<Information>(infoList);` is also pass by reference,

Comment: @user6703592 I have updated the Information class. It was a mistake, thank you. 
`new List<Information>(infoList)` creates a new instance
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ gypsyCoder how to use `Extensions` method？

Comment: @user6703592 you can follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx

Comment: @ gypsyCoder  for 2 I also have a question, see the updated quetion

Comment: @ gypsyCode you mean replace every `=` by `.clone()`?

Comment: @user6703592 yes, I think, you should for each complex class type

Comment: @ gypsyCode and every new class should add the clone method?

Comment: @user6703592 yes.

Comment: For the `Extension Method`, why the result type is `IList`? Should we add the `ToList()` at end. And `List<NewClass>  A.Clone()` is totally a new List whatever how complex the `NewClass` is?

Answer (score 2):

You could overload the constructor, that way the empty one can still be used as well as one that takes in an object to copy eg.

```
public class Information
{
    public Tuple<string, string> pair { get; set; }
    public double Signal { get; set; }
    public double SigmaMove { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public Information()
    {}

    public Information(Information Tem)
    {
        pair = Tem.pair;
        Signal  = Tem.Signal ;
        SigmaMove = Tem.SigmaMove;
        Date = Tem.Date;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class `information` needs to implement iClonable
Go have a look at a few answers in [How to Clone Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359318/how-to-clone-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Not a very elegant method, in fact crude, but works .... I serialize the list into a json string and deserialize it back into the new required list. The reference between the two is no longer there and each list can be manipulated independently of the other.